# how to translate expressions involving "of" into German

Tags: preposition

I am conducting a research to find a way how to translate the English expression "of XXX" into German.

A have found that there are three different options to express it (sometimes only some, sometimes all can be used).

1. a compound noun
2. "von"
3. genitive case

Let's consider these 5 sentences (numbered 1 to 5) and their 3 options:

1. "the color of the car"

   - die Autofarbe
   - die Farbe von dem Auto (die Farbe vom Auto)
   - die Farbe des Autos
2. "the photo of the car"

   - das Autofoto
   - das Foto von dem Auto (das Foto vom Auto)
   - das Foto des Autos
3. "the photo of you"

   - das Dufoto - I think that is a nonsense.
   - das Foto von dir
   - das Foto des dein - I think that is a nonsense too.
4. "the president of France"

   - der Frankreichspräsident
   - der Präsident von Frankreich
   - der Präsident des Frankreichs
5. "the beauty of Prague"

   - die Pragschönheit
   - die Schönheit von Prag
   - die Schönheit des Prags

My conclusion here: it is not possible to state a rule for every expression. (E.g. "photo of XXX" should be translated only using b) in the 3) sentence, but in the sentence 2) all options a, b and c are possible  - it also depends on what you are taking a photo of.)

Questions:

- What are your thoughts about these sentences?
- What is your idea of a rule how to translate "of XXX" into German?
- A German friend has suggested the option "Frankreichs Präsident". Is this a form of the genitive? If yes, where is the word "des" here missing (same for "Prags Schönheit")?

Comment: 3-5) wcould be better: dein Photo, Frankreichs Präsident, Prags Schönheit instead of your genetive choice.

Comment: 3c wäre "Dein Photo".

Comment: your conclusion is right: no rule that covers all - neither general nor exceptional usage. Rule of thumb - possible.

Comment: “Des Frankreichs” would correspond to “von dem Frankreich”, both are wrong here. This is not about possessives but about when to use a definite article.

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/gender-of-country-names-without-articles

Comment: Der Präsident Frankreichs vs Frankreichs Präsident: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/52752/der-widerspenstigen-z%c3%a4hmung

Answer (score 2):

A compound noun is a possible option for many cases, but you happened to pick 5 exemples where it is not suitable.

1. *the color of the car*

   - die Autofarbe - As @guidot stated in his answer, that would rather mean *the paint for the car* (even though der Autolack would be more usual)
   - die Farbe vom Auto / die Farbe des Autos - both are ok.
2. *the photo of the car*

   - das Autofoto - very unusual. People would probably guess it means a photo that was taken by an **auto**matic device.
   - das Foto vom Auto / das Foto des Autos - both are ok.
3. *the photo of you*
   You correctly guessed that #1 and #3 are nonsense. *Das Foto von dir* is fine, as well as *Dein Foto* as suggested in @mic's comment.
   Note that both could either mean *the photo of you* (you are on it) as well as *the photo from you* (you have taken it). You can only know which one is meant from context.
4. and 5. Since *Frankreich* and *Prag* are (proper) names, genitive works a bit differend here. It is expressed by the "s" added to the name (instead of the word *des*).
   *Der Präsident von Frankreich*, *Frankreich**s** Präsident* or *der Präsident Frankreich**s*** all are correct. Idiomatically you would often say *der französische Präsident* (the French president).
   Similar you could say *die Schönheit von Prag*, *die Schönheit Prag**s*** or *Prag**s** Schönheit*.
   There is also the form *die prager Schönheit*, but that would mean *the beauty from Prague* (a beautiful woman from there).

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer on that one, since my dictionary lists 11 different meanings for *of*. While *south of Paris* also would translate to *südlich von Paris* this is only superficially the same word.

Some rules of thumb:

- use *von* if in doubt concerning the genitive - it will likely be understood
- Stay clear of forming new composite nouns: *Autofarbe* would more likely be understood as a paint for cars than as a color of a car. The answers to [your question here](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/56725/1696) still apply.
- Personal pronouns are seldom valid building blocks for compound nouns.

Comment: a) Was spricht dagegen den Genitiv zu lernen - traust Du es unserem Publikum nicht zu? b) "Die Zeugen widersprachen sich bezüglich der Autofarbe." Ich meine, dass der Kontext meist klärt, wie das zu verstehen ist.